# i am trying to sent sms through serial port event listener but i am grtting this error NoSuchPortException

Tags: java, sms

Week before this code working perfectly but after formating the system it is giving NoSuchPortException while trying to send sms connect my nokia c3 cell phone via usb

error log is as

```
enter code here`INFO: Server startup in 17344 ms
+919032055002     null
problem is here in getting port number
javax.comm.NoSuchPortException
Port id is : null
at javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(CommPortIdentifier.java:105)
at com.gces.sms.SerialConnection.openConnection(SerialConnection.java:73)
at com.gces.sms.Sender.send(Sender.java:68)
at com.gces.sms.SMSClient.run(SMSClient.java:38)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
in sms client & msg is :  null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.gces.sms.SerialConnection.openConnection(SerialConnection.java:90)
at com.gces.sms.Sender.send(Sender.java:68)
at com.gces.sms.SMSClient.run(SMSClient.java:38)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and code is here

```
package com.gces.sms;

import javax.comm.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.TextArea;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.TooManyListenersException;

public class SerialConnection implements SerialPortEventListener,
                 CommPortOwnershipListener {

private SerialParameters parameters;
private OutputStream os;
private InputStream is;
private KeyHandler keyHandler;

private CommPortIdentifier portId;
private SerialPort sPort;

private boolean open;

private String receptionString="";

public String getIncommingString(){
  byte[] bVal= receptionString.getBytes();
  receptionString="";
  return new String (bVal);
}
public SerialConnection(SerialParameters parameters) {
    this.parameters = parameters;
open = false;
}
public void openConnection() throws SerialConnectionException {

try {

    portId = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(parameters.getPortName());
} catch (NoSuchPortException e) {
        System.out.println("problem is here in getting port number");
        e.printStackTrace();
}catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   System.out.println("Port id is : "+portId);
try {
    sPort = (SerialPort)portId.open("SMSConnector", 30000);
} catch (PortInUseException e) {

    throw new SerialConnectionException(e.getMessage());
}
    sPort.sendBreak(1000);

try {
    setConnectionParameters();
} catch (SerialConnectionException e) {
    sPort.close();
    throw e;
}
try {
    os = sPort.getOutputStream();
    is = sPort.getInputStream();
} catch (IOException e) {
    sPort.close();
    throw new SerialConnectionException("Error opening i/o streams");
}
try {
    sPort.addEventListener(this);
} catch (TooManyListenersException e) {
    sPort.close();
    throw new SerialConnectionException("too many listeners added");
}
sPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
try {
    sPort.enableReceiveTimeout(30);
} catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {
}
portId.addPortOwnershipListener(this);

open = true;
}

 public void setConnectionParameters() throws SerialConnectionException {


int oldBaudRate = sPort.getBaudRate();
int oldDatabits = sPort.getDataBits();
int oldStopbits = sPort.getStopBits();
int oldParity   = sPort.getParity();
int oldFlowControl = sPort.getFlowControlMode();

try {
    sPort.setSerialPortParams(parameters.getBaudRate(),
                  parameters.getDatabits(),
                  parameters.getStopbits(),
                  parameters.getParity());
} catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {
    parameters.setBaudRate(oldBaudRate);
    parameters.setDatabits(oldDatabits);
    parameters.setStopbits(oldStopbits);
    parameters.setParity(oldParity);
    throw new SerialConnectionException("Unsupported parameter");
}

try {
    sPort.setFlowControlMode(parameters.getFlowControlIn()
                   | parameters.getFlowControlOut());
} catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {
    throw new SerialConnectionException("Unsupported flow control");
}
}

public void closeConnection() {
if (!open) {
    return;
}

if (sPort != null) {
    try {
        os.close();
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println(e);
    }
    sPort.close();
    portId.removePortOwnershipListener(this);
}

open = false;
}
public void sendBreak() {
sPort.sendBreak(1000);
}
public boolean isOpen() {
return open;
}
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent e) {
StringBuffer inputBuffer = new StringBuffer();
int newData = 0;

switch (e.getEventType()) {

    case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
        while (newData != -1) {
            try {
                newData = is.read();
            if (newData == -1) {
            break;
            }
            if ('\r' == (char)newData) {
            inputBuffer.append('\n');
            } else {
                inputBuffer.append((char)newData);
            }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println(ex);
                return;
            }
        }
    receptionString=receptionString+ (new String(inputBuffer));

    break;

    case SerialPortEvent.BI:
    receptionString=receptionString+("\n--- BREAK RECEIVED ---\n");
}

}

public void ownershipChange(int type) {
  /*
if (type == CommPortOwnershipListener.PORT_OWNERSHIP_REQUESTED) {
    PortRequestedDialog prd = new PortRequestedDialog(parent);
}
    */
}

class KeyHandler extends KeyAdapter {
OutputStream os;

/**
Creates the KeyHandler.
@param os The OutputStream for the port.
*/
public KeyHandler(OutputStream os) {
    super();
    this.os = os;
}

/**
Handles the KeyEvent.
Gets the <code>char</char> generated by the <code>KeyEvent</code>,
converts it to an <code>int</code>, writes it to the <code>
OutputStream</code> for the port.
*/
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt) {
        char newCharacter = evt.getKeyChar();
        if ((int)newCharacter==10) newCharacter = '\r';
        System.out.println ((int)newCharacter);
    try {
        os.write((int)newCharacter);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("OutputStream write error: " + e);
    }
    }
}
    public void send(String message) {
        byte[] theBytes= (message+"\n").getBytes();
        for (int i=0; i<theBytes.length;i++){

          char newCharacter = (char)theBytes[i];
          if ((int)newCharacter==10) newCharacter = '\r';

      try {
        os.write((int)newCharacter);
          } catch (IOException e) {
              System.err.println("OutputStream write error: " + e);
          }

        }
        //System.out.println (">'" +message +"' sent");




    }



 }
```

and the second file code is as

```
package com.gces.sms;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Date;

import com.gces.sms.SerialConnection;
import com.gces.sms.SerialConnectionException;
import com.gces.sms.SerialParameters;

public class Sender implements Runnable  {

private static final long STANDARD=500;
private static final long LONG=2000;
private static final long  VERYLONG=20000;

SerialConnection mySerial =null;

static final private char cntrlZ=(char)26;
String in, out;
Thread aThread=null;
private long delay=STANDARD;
String recipient=null;
String message=null;

 //private String csca="+919084051550"; // the message center uninor
 //private String csca="+919837099995"; // the message center idea
 private String csca="+919032055002"; // the message center docomo
 private SerialParameters defaultParameters= new SerialParameters ("COM4",9600,0,0,8,1,0);
 public int step;
 public int status=-1;
 public long messageNo=-1;
 public Sender(String recipient, String message){

 this.recipient=recipient;
 this.message=message;

 }

 public int send () throws Exception {
  File file = new File("C:\\db_backup\\SMS.txt");
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
  String line = null;
  String port = null;
  int flag=0;
  while( (line = br.readLine())!= null ){
      if(flag==0)
          port=line;
      else if(flag==1)
          csca=line;
      else
          br.close();
      flag++;
  }
  //br.close();
  defaultParameters= new SerialParameters (port,9600,0,0,8,1,0);
 SerialParameters params = defaultParameters;
 System.out.println(csca+"     "+port); 
 mySerial =new SerialConnection (params);


    mySerial.openConnection();

 aThread=new Thread(this);

 aThread.start() ;
 //log("start");

 return 0;
 }

public void run(){

boolean timeOut=false;
long startTime=(new Date()).getTime();



 while ((step <7) && (!timeOut)){
 timeOut=((new Date()).getTime() - startTime)>delay;

  //if atz does not work, type to send cntrlZ and retry, in case a message was stuck
  if (timeOut && (step==1)) {
      step=-1;
      mySerial.send(        ""+cntrlZ);
  }

  //read incoming string
  String result=  mySerial.getIncommingString() ;

  //System.out.println("<- in rrrrrrrrrr "+result+"\n--------");
  int expectedResult=-1;

  try{
    //log ("Step:"+step);

    switch (step){
      case 0:

        mySerial.send("atz");
        delay=LONG;
        startTime=(new Date()).getTime();
        break;

      case 1:
        delay=STANDARD;
        mySerial.send("ath0");
        startTime=(new Date()).getTime();
        break;
      case 2:
        expectedResult=result.indexOf("OK");

        //log ("received ok ="+expectedResult);
        if (expectedResult>-1){
          mySerial.send("at+cmgf=1");
          startTime=(new Date()).getTime();
        }else{
            step=step-1;
        }
        break;
      case 3:
        expectedResult=result.indexOf("OK");

       // log ("received ok ="+expectedResult);
        if (expectedResult>-1){
          mySerial.send("at+csca=\""+csca+"\"");
          startTime=(new Date()).getTime();
        }else{
          step=step-1;
        }

        break;
      case 4:
        expectedResult=result.indexOf("OK");

       // log ("received ok ="+expectedResult);
        if (expectedResult>-1){
          mySerial.send("at+cmgs=\""+recipient+"\"");
          startTime=(new Date()).getTime();
        }else{
          step=step-1;
        }

        break;
      case 5:
        expectedResult=result.indexOf(">");

        //log ("received ok ="+expectedResult);
        if (expectedResult>-1){
          mySerial.send(message+cntrlZ);
          startTime=(new Date()).getTime();
        }else{
          step=step-1;
        }
        delay=VERYLONG;//waiting for message ack

        break;

      case 6:
        expectedResult=result.indexOf("OK");
        //read message number
        if (expectedResult>-1){
          int n=result.indexOf("CMGS:");
          result=result.substring(n+5);
          //System.out.println(result);
          n=result.indexOf("\n");
          status=0;
         // result="1                        11";
          try{
              messageNo=Long.parseLong(result.substring(0,n).trim() );
              }
              catch(NumberFormatException e){
                  //result="1                                    ";
                  messageNo=1;
              }
          log ("sent message no:"+messageNo);


        }else{
          step=step-1;
        }

      break;
    }
    step=step+1;

    aThread.sleep(100);

   }catch (Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }

  mySerial.closeConnection() ;

  //if timed out set status

   if (timeOut ) {
    status=-2;
    log("*** time out at step "+step+"***");
  }
 }
  private void log(String s){
  System.out.println (new java.util.Date()+":"+this.getClass().getName()+":"+s);
 }
 }
```

This code working fine but after formating the system gives these error ...

Comment: Did you try to undo those changes and then imlment them in smaller steps? Also this question is off topic and would belong on Stack Overflow. Though not sure if they would accept it there, maybe you could reduce the amount of code to the amount that is related to the actual problem you have.

Comment: thnx thorsten, i am trying to give a full view of my code and problem so m posted so lengthy code

Comment: @SumitChoudhary I doubt anyone is going to read through all that code. What exactly did you do that caused this error? What do you mean by "formatting the system"?

Comment: thnx fogivenson for ur response, this code is deployed on tomcat and working well but after format the system(re-install the windows) sms is not sending and gives the exception as NoSuchPortException .. now plz help me out what to do..